# PHP Loop only displaying 1 value, should display 2

Tags: php, loops

I've been trying to get a PHP loop working for the past hour, having trouble getting more then 1 item displayed, here's the output of the array: http://pastie.org/6429971

Here's my code:

```
$url = 'https://www.eventbrite.com/json/user_list_events?app_key=HIDEN&user=HIDDEN';

$events = json_decode(get_data($url));
$i = 0;

foreach ($events as $event) { 
    // print_r($event[$i]);
    echo $event[$i]->event->title;
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a foreach loop you don't have to use a variable `$i`, and you have to point out to the array containing the events. After which you can traverse that array with an foreach loop.

```
$url = 'https://www.eventbrite.com/json/user_list_events?app_key=HIDEN&user=HIDDEN';

$events = json_decode(get_data($url));
$events = $events->events;

foreach ($events as $event){
  echo $event->title;
}
```